# Facebook c# sdk - How to know if the user is using the app for the first time

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to know if a user uses the Facebook App for his first time.
Is there any information on cookie returned about it, or do i have to create a database and store the users ids for example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook does not provide this information for you (nor does the C# SDK). You will have to track this yourself in a database or something.